# What is the best database design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am only about a week into learning Rails (4) and am creating a simple app. I have four tables.

1) Lions
2) Panthers
3) Trainers
4) Toys

- A toy can belong to either a lion or a panther. A toy will only belong to one cat at a time (So it seems best to make this polymorphic. The next part is where I become unsure.)
- A trainer can train either a lion, a panther or both.
- A lion or panther can have more than one trainer.

I made the Trainers table polymorphic, but upon seeding each trainer with first a lion then a panther, I saw that the panthers overrode the lions. It seems I would have to create another instance of each trainer to give them a second cat, which would also give that same trainer a second ID, which I don't want. Perhaps a many_to_many design between Lions/Trainers and Panthers/Trainers would be better? My questions about that are, once I make the join table for each many_to_many, when I want to list the cats that each trainer trains, will this require two loops, one through the lions_trainers and also the panthers_trainers? And Is this even the best approach? Admittedly, this would be easier if Lions and Panthers were in one table, but that is not in the assignment. Suggestions/Input appreciated :)

Comment: Why do you have separate tables for panthers vs lions? Think about this carefully: those cat types might be different in reality, but for the purposes of your app, aren't they both simply training subjects? Once you resolve that question, a lot of the mental gymnastics that you're doing go right out the window.

Comment: lol, i totally agree that they should be in the same table!! but this is a homework assignment, and the assignment specified they are in two different tables (for the purposes of using polymorphism for the toy). I am the one who decided to go overboard and decide each cat can have more than one trainer. things have been complicated every since :(

Comment: maybe i will just scale back and stick to the assignment, but would still be interested in any suggestions to how to get what I originally set out to do accomplished :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you need to create an "abstract" table for cats,
that will have a 1:1 relationship with both the lions table and with the panthers table, and have a many to many relationship table between the cat table and the trainer table.